# Linker outfile property file does not match targetpath?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, linker-errors, sierrachart

I'm trying to compile a C++ type .DLL for a *SierraChart* custom *study*.
(Which is a financial trading application.) Here is the warning I get that I need to fix so it all points to the linker output value:

```
warning MSB8012:

TargetPath(C:\SierraChart\VCProject\Release\SCStudies.dll) does not match the Linker's 
OutputFile property value (c:\sierrachart\data\SCStudies.dll).

This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please
make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt)
property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried following the steps suggested in the warning: "To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile)."

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure how to do that. I'm kind of a newb to attaching visual studio to processes and with C++.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876429/how-do-i-fix-warning-msb8012-in-a-static-library-project-in-visual-c-2010

Answer (score 14):

I believe this warning appears specifically when upgrading a C++ project to VS2010. [Visual Studio 2010 C++ Project Upgrade Guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/03/02/visual-studio-2010-c-project-upgrade-guide.aspx) describes some of the caveats encountered during an upgrade. If you're uncomfortable changing project settings, then retaining the older version of Visual Studio, may work for you.

To change the `%(Link.OutputFile)`, open the project properties. Navigate to Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General. You can set the Output File to `$(OutDir)\SCStudies.dll`, which should take care of your issue. You may need to repeat the change for each Configuration/Flavor you will be building (Debug/x86, Release/x86, Debug/Itanium, etc...).

Answer (score 8):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29728807/1257607).

I changed the following property:

> Linker -> General -> Output File to
>   "$(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)"

This prevented the warning to appear and the output was generated successfully.

Answer (score 1):

The original configuration was set like:

> Properties -> Linker -> General : `$(OutDir)\"<'name fileA>".exe`

The program tries to run "`<'name_project>`".exe and as result error Linked.

You need to set the configuration as:

> Properties -> Linker -> General : `$(OutDir)\"<'project name>".exe`

Answer (score 1):

A different fix which others haven't mentioned is that by default the TargetExt is `.exe` and for my debug builds I changed it to be `_d.exe`, where instead you should be doing that in the TargetName path.

Answer (score 1):

The directory specified in General->Output Directory and the directory specified in the path at Linker->Output File have to match.

If you want to change the defaults do things in these order:
You first configure the OutDir in General->Output Directory. E.g.

```
$(SolutionDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\MyProgram\
```

Make sure Output File is consistent. E.g. this would work

```
$(OutDir)\$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)
```

Answer (score 1):

The comment from Gerardo Hernandez helped me.

*The directory specified in General->Output Directory and the directory specified in the path at Linker->Output File have to match.*

In my case I was importing a large project from Visual Studio 6 and

`C:\Project\myproject\OneOfMyDlls\.\Debug\OneOfMyDlls.dll`

was not equal to

`C:\Project\myproject\Debug\OneOfMyDlls.dll`

but

`C:\Project\myproject\OneOfMyDlls\..\Debug\OneOfMyDlls.dll`

would have been, after path reduction.

The problem was that the Visual Studio 2017 import had changed the output directory from
`..\Debug` to `.\Debug` assuming that the unconventional parent directory use was a mistake. In a large project with 13 DLLs of our own, (never mind second and third party DLLs too), it makes sense to collect all the DLLs in one place and `..\Debug` was correct.

So while others might have had to change `Linker->Output File`, in my case it was `General->Output Directory` which needed to change as it had been corrupted by the import from Visual Studio 6.

Something like `..\Debug` had become something like `.\Debug` after import. (The real project specific names have been removed .)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not significant for the program:

[Odd Visual Studio error when following the custom study video](https://www.sierrachart.com/supportboard/showthread.php?p=173985#post173985)

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you return to Visual Studio after 20 years, you may not know where the project properties are. In VS 2012: top of the screen "FILE EDIT VIEW PROJECT BUILD..." : choose PROJECT. Properties is the last item in the menu. Indeed for me there was a mismatch in the target name, too.