# How can I set the output path of a vc++ project different than its dependencies (nuget)?

Tags: warnings, visual-c++-2015

**Premise**
I have a Visual Studio 2015 solution containing different VC++ projects.
Some of them (EXE and some DLLs) have the $OutDir set to default "$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\" (i.e. "C:\MySolution\Debug\").
For some other projects (DLLs), I need to change the output path to a sub-directory of the "default" $OutDir (i.e. "C:\MySolution\Debug\Pieces\".

Example directory tree:

```
  C:\MySolution\Debug\  
    MyProgram.exe  
    Dependency.dll  
    .\Pieces\  
      MyPiece1.dll  
      MyPiece2.dll
```

**Constraints**
the "Pieces" DLLs depends on a third-party Dependency.dll (through NuGet package), which I cannot modify.

**Usual solution**
The usual way for this is to change the $OutDir project setting for "pieces" projects, but this will also force their dependencies to be output in the same sub-dir.
This is not wanted and also created problems in debugging and packaging of the entire solution.

**What I tried so far**
I tried to:
 1. keep the $OutDir the same for all projects
 2. change the "pieces" $TargetName to "Pieces\$(ProjectName)"
This seems to work (both MyPiece*.dlland Dependency.dll are correctly placed and debugging is fine), but unfortunately Visual Studio generates the following warning:

> warning MSB8012: TargetName(Pieces\MyPiece1.dll) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (MyPiece1). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).

This warning is somewhat confusing, because the %Link.OutputFile in the project settings looks correct:
$(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)  =>  C:\MySolution\Debug\Pieces\MyPiece1.dll

**Question**
What is the correct approach to solve my problem?
How do I force Visual Studio to output some of the generated files in a different path, but still having their Nuget dependencies in the "default" $OutDir?

I've searched the web and StackOverflow already, but I can't find a suitable answer.
Note: my problem is not related to upgrading a pre-VS2010 solution (as in [Microsoft official notes on warning MSB8012 after solution upgrade](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2010/03/02/visual-studio-2010-c-project-upgrade-guide/) and [asked on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876429/how-do-i-fix-warning-msb8012-in-a-static-library-project-in-visual-c-2010)).

Comment: Have you considered using a post-build event on each of the Pieces projects to simply `copy` the compiled DLLs and PDBs to the paths where you need them?  It's a pretty low-tech hack, but it's often good enough.

Comment: @SeanWerkema Yes, post-build 'move' files is one of the options I've investigated, but unfortunately it creates errors in the automated build, especially when activating parallel builds.

Comment: Are you sure your project dependencies are set up correctly? If you get errors during parallel builds that you don't get with serial builds, you may have a broken/invalid dependency graph. There's no reason anything that depends on those copies should be invoked before they've completed, either in a manual build or in an automated build.

Comment: @SeanWerkema Errors are clearly referring to the copy file operation. Errors are more frequent if I use the VS GUI available post-build events, less frequent if I manually add MSBuild Copy Tasks in the .vcxproj files.

Comment: I'm not sure what form of `copy` you're using, but this is what I use, and it works. In the _pre-build_ event of the _consumers_ of a library, I have this command: `copy /y "$(SolutionDir)SomeLibrary\bin\$(Platform)-$(Configuration)\SomeLibrary.*" "$(ProjectDir)bin\$(Platform)-$(Configuration)"`  You might need to tweak the paths in your case, but I have never had a failed build using that pattern.  (Notice also that it's `SomeLibrary.*` — that copies the `.pdb` files as well, which makes debugging a lot easier.)