# How to force msbuild to ignore warning MSB8012

Tags: msbuild

I know this question was discussed hundreds of times, but I still cannot find solution. Maybe something was changed in msbuild and I am not aware. The problem is that I get the following warning

```
warning MSB8012: TargetPath(d:\src\output\Techd.dll) does not match the Linker's OutputFile 
property value (d:\src\output\Debug32\bin\Techd.dll). This may cause your project to build 
incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and
$(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
```

I change the outdir by property

```
msbuild.wxw /p:OutDir="my_out_dir"
```

I cannot change projects properties and I am not allowed to modify msbuild target files (Microsoft.CppBuild.targets). So don't have any idea hot to force msbuild to ignore this warning or to ignore the $OutDir variable's change.

Comment: Possible answer : [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876429/how-do-i-fix-warning-msb8012-in-a-static-library-project-in-visual-c-2010)

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to silence MSBuild warnings using a command line parameter:

```
msbuild.exe /nowarn:MSB8012
```

In an upcoming update to MSBuild/VS2017 (15.3), you can specify properties to control MSBuild warnings in project files as a property, so that it also affects builds in VS:

```
<MSBuildWarningsAsMessages>MSB8012</MSBuildWarningsAsMessages>
```

Comment: For current msbuild version /nowarn works only for compile warnings, MSB8012 is msbuild warning.

Comment: Which version are you using? The current (15/15.1) version should be able to use `/nowarn` as command line argument to suppress msbuild warnings (different than compile warnings)

Comment: which is just a short form for `/warnasmessage:`

Comment: Our version is older. 14.0 We use VS 2015

Comment: Is it possible to install latest version of MSBuild and use it with vs2015?

Comment: Not really. Yes those suppress options are new to vs2017/msbuild 15

Comment: That is why I am lost. Really don't know how to handle this problem