# Can't rebuild on linux remotely project with static library: error MS8012, Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, linux, static-libraries, remote-debugging, visual-studio-2019

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

I have static library in project and trying to debug it on remote linux.

I tried to changes paths in properties, but i can't understand which one i have to change

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning MSB8012 TargetPath(C:\Users\Lekus\source\repos\CheckingApp\libraryForApp\bin\x64\Debug\liblibraryForApp.a) does not match the Library's OutputFile property value (C:\Users\Lekus\source\repos\CheckingApp\libraryForApp\~\projects\libraryForApp\bin\x64\Debug\liblibraryForApp.a). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Lib.OutputFile). libraryForApp   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets  1445
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix warning MSB8012 in a static library project in Visual C++ 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876429/how-do-i-fix-warning-msb8012-in-a-static-library-project-in-visual-c-2010)

Comment: no, it is another problem. because of remote compiling

Comment: please add your images as text to your question. img1 is cutting of text