# Migrating VS 2008 project to 2012, compiles, "Unable to start program"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2008, mfc, migration

I am given this VS project as a test and I am supposed to modify it.

It is a VS 9.0 project and I upgraded it to 2012 (I tried openning it with a VS 2008 it tells me that the project is written in an older version[+](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bf9zrjx95jen9tw/Screenshot%202014-10-08%2011.01.29.png?dl=0).) I upgraded it and  also followed the modifications suggested [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/562386/Lessons-learned-migrating-to-Visual-Studio-an) and basically changed the properties mentioned in the pictures for both the debug and the release mode. Unfortunately the program compiles, but it gives me the error:

"*unable to start program the system cannot find file specified*"

Have I messed up something in the project properties?

---

Not sure if relevant, but the project uses MFC for which I included the header and the library files from: :...\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\atlmfc... I was getting:

*#error Please use the /MD switch for _AFXDLL builds*

and to get rid of that, I set:

*Use /MD (Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation) and shared MFC (Properties -> General -> Use of MFC)* 
as was suggested on the forums.
Almost definitely not relevant, but thought I would mention it!

Comment: Does it fail to start from the debugger or the shell?

Comment: @Niall it's a run time error.

Comment: have you tried adding files from VS2012 i-e :...\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\atlmfc

Comment: @AliKazmi I thought of doing that, but the 11 version of AtlMFC was missing some of the files.(http://goo.gl/gwqoTU) so I thought I would sticking to the 9 version.

Comment: you can install them by using VS setup file

Comment: The debug output window may help. Also undo the change to which mfc headers you are using.

Comment: @AliKazmi I don't see why the current installation would has done a partial installation of the MFC files. :/ But I guess I could try that.

Comment: @Yakk http://goo.gl/r83t87

Comment: I'd correct the warnings as directed in the MSBx messages, this generally leads to "easier" location etc. and predictability of the output. In addition to the "cannot find the file specified", this may be why - the debug build expects an output that is not there. You can check this by adding the path of the debug-able target to the "debug command" (section debug) of the project properties.

Comment: Ah how did I miss that... OutputFile, the value defined at Linker -> General -> Output File, had a different value to my target values. Fixing that got rid of that problem!

Comment: May I suggest this to be linked to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494028/warning-msb8012-make-sure-that-outdir-targetname-and-targetext-prope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up having to install the ultimate version of VS.