# warning MSB8012 - Building a Visual Studio 2003 project on Visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2003

I'm trying to build a **Visual Studio 2003 project** (SimpleIni) on **Visual studio 2015**.

After opening the project it provided me an option to Auto upgrade it. 
However after upgrading I'm unable to Build the solution and getting following warnings:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1189,5): warning MSB8012: TargetPath(E:\abc\VisualStudioCpp\test\simpleini-master\Debug Unicode\SimpleIni.exe) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (E:\abc\VisualStudioCpp\test\simpleini-master\Debug Unicode\testsi.exe). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1191,5): warning MSB8012: TargetName(SimpleIni) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (testsi). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
1>ConvertUTF.obj : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/SAFESEH' specification
```

I have gone through the following links:

[warning MSB8012 : make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494028/warning-msb8012-make-sure-that-outdir-targetname-and-targetext-prope)

[How do I fix warning MSB8012 in a static library project in Visual C++ 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876429/how-do-i-fix-warning-msb8012-in-a-static-library-project-in-visual-c-2010)

However I'm not able to find how to change Linker settings on Visual Studio 2015.

Can someone tell me how to build a Visual Studio 2003 project on Visual studio 2015?

Comment: In most cases provided warnings don't fail the build. What is the error Visual Studio 2015 shows to you?

Comment: @Nikita: If I try to run the program I'm getting following error: `'"E:\abc\VisualStudioCpp\test\simpleini-master\Debug Unicode\SimpleIni.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: In your case this error means `Sim pleIni.exe` doesn't exist. But what the errors you see when you do the Solution Rebuild in VS2015?

Comment: I'm not getting any error only warnings which I have already posted, however because of these warning I'm not able to execute the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the problem you should change the options for you project as follows:

> General tab -> Target Name = SimpleIni, Target Extension = .exe

Also on General tab check that application type of your project is *Application*.

All of these options marked on the attached screenshot:
[image]

> Linker tab -> All parameters -> Output file -> $(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)

This option is marked on the screenshot bellow:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If you could add some snapshot then It will surely be helpful, because in the links which I have mentioned they have provided the same answer.

Comment: @user3898160 Yes, but in the mentioned links too many information you don't need to fix your issue. I will attach the screens with configs to make it more clear

Comment: @user3898160 Probably updated answer will help more, please check it.

Comment: Wonderful...Thanks

Comment: Just for future reference: Click on Solution Explore and Select your project, right click and select Properties then you can apply these configuration changes.